# Why are two strings that are both the letter 'a' not equal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean, typeof

I am using jQuery to grab the text of a button and want to compare that text to a letter in a string. I haven't been able to get it to return true. Below is just a simplified example of what I am trying to do.

the first console log returns "a" "string"
the second console log is taking an element that has the text of the letter a in it an returns "a" "string"

even though it seems they are the exact same, when I check if they are equal using a boolean it returns false.

```
<div class="button">
     <p>a</p>
</div>
```

```
console.log (`a`, typeof `a`)
console.log ($element.text(), typeof $element.text())
console.log('a' == $element.text());
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: what is the type and value of $element.text() ?

Comment: There must some spaces in the string. [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) before comparing